# How do I unload a kdb partitioned database?

Tags: kdb

I loaded (mapped) a partitioned database with the \l command. How can I unmap the database? This can be useful for a number of reasons, like loading a different db with the same name or freeing some system memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no command to do this. You could manually delete all the variables that were created when the database was mapped. So delete sym, date (if your database contains a date partitioned table) and all the tables that were loaded.

```
/ delete sym, date, quote and trade from the default namespace
delete sym, date, quote, trade from `.

/ or if you want to delete everything in the default namespace
delete from `.
```

After doing this you could call .Q.gc[] - to return memory to the os. Not pretty, but I think it's the only way.

Comment: Do you know if I have to reload the database after I remove or add date directories on disk? I seem to have query problems after I add new dates to my partitioned database.

Comment: Yes, you should reload. To delete all of the partitioned tables only from the global context, you can use `![\`.;();0b;.Q.pt]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `Q.gc[]` call to the [garbage collector](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qgc-garbage-collect)

Comment: I don't have any valid do_unmap or do_munmap command at the Q prompt.

Comment: I don't think that unmaps the database, it's only to reclaim the memory freed by deleted variables.

Comment: see http://www.timestored.com/kdb-guides/memory-management for tips on memory management. i haven't found a better way for what you want

Comment: Right, close but there isn't really an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

\l does not increase the memory usage by q significantly. its the variables you create and computations you run which consume the memory.
so as mnestor said

delete from `.
.Q.gc[]

should solve your problem of name conflict and memory management.
To avoid deleting something which might be needed, just move it to another namespace.
E.g .n.somethinguseful